# d3.nest turns key into string value

Tags: d3.js

I have the following code in d3

```
const weeksOfYear = d3.nest()
 .key(d => d.dateObj.week())
 .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
 .entries(pics);
```

the `d.dateObj` property is a Moment.js object. The `.week()` method returns a number.

Somehwere in `d3.nest()` it turns the key into a string value and so I am getting alphabetical sorting on what should be a numerical order.
I.e., my output is:

```
1
10
11
12
13
2
20
21
22
23
...
```

Whereas I want it ordered `1,2,3,4...`

I haven't found the trick yet in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Analysis

The `d3.nest()` does internally [make use](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/src/nest.js#L21) of [`d3.map()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#map) when building the nested structure. And, as the documentation on `d3.map()` has it:

> - Keys are coerced to strings.

This is explicitly taken care of when building the nested structure by coercing the [`keyValue`](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection/blob/master/src/nest.js#L26) to a string:

```
if (values = valuesByKey.get(keyValue = key(value = array[i]) + "")) {
```

---

#### Solution

D3's comparator [`d3.ascending`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#ascending) will not convert strings to numbers before comparison. To do a numerical comparison of the keys, you need to wrap this comparator and do the conversion beforehand:

```
const weeksOfYear = d3.nest()
 .key(d => d.dateObj.week())
 .sortKeys((a, b) => d3.ascending(+a, +b))
 .entries(pics);
```

Comment: So is it d3.nest() turning the key into a string to begin with? The key value is a number to begin with.